# Nodejs: Save stdout when the process throws error

Tags: node.js, cypress

In nodejs script, I am using execAsync to run cypress tests. Obviously, some tests would fail but that returns error status code 1 and it would fail the script and stop next steps to merge test reports and html report creation.

Solution is to use try catch as follows

```
import { execSync } from "child_process";
let stdout = "";
try {
 stdout = execSync("npx cypress run", { stdio: "inherit" });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("stdout=[" + stdout + "]");
  const regex = /\d+ of \d+ failed/;
  if (!regex.test(stdout)) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Since throw is happening, stdout comes as empty string and console.log(err) gets executed and shows below

```
       Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped  
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ ✖  todo.cy.js                               351ms        6        -        1        -        5 │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    ✖  1 of 1 failed (100%)                     351ms        6        -        1        -        5  

stdout=[]
Error: Command failed: npx cypress run
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:841:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:912:15)
    at file:///home/atulk/workspace/cypress-all/cypress-reports/test.mjs:5:12
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 35512,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

I do not want to show the error when the tests have failed. What could be the way to catch the stdout so that I can look for the string like "1 of 1 failed"?

Comment: Remove `console.log(err);`

Comment: @Konrad I need to print error if that is happening due to something else apart from test failure. Removing is not a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find it is easier to use the Cypress [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#Examples) which is designed for running Cypress from Node.

For example,

```js
// e2e-run-tests.js
const cypress = require('cypress')

cypress
  .run({
    // the path is relative to the current working directory
    spec: './cypress/e2e/examples/actions.cy.js',
  })
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

Comment: Nice one. I had no idea about this. Let me explore this.